# Is it possible to turn a shortcut to a folder into a menu of items in that folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I vaguely remember seeing something on the internet that showed it was possible to turn any shortcut to a folder into a menu, as long as that shortcut was in the start menu or on the quicklaunch bar (i.e. somewhere that allowed menu functionality)  Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, how to do it?

I'd like to be able to do this...

[image: a screenshot of a menu]

With a link in my quicklaunch area...

[image: a screenshot of the link]

I remember it had something to do with renaming the shortcut with a long string of characters placed between '{' and '}'.

I realize how picky this request is as I have more or less achieved what I am looking for by placing the 'desktop' toolbar on my start bar.  But I'd rather it be an icon in my quicklaunch.  Just humour me :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the taskbar and select Toolbars>New Toolbar. Then select the folder you want. When you have the folder selected it may try to show all the content on the taskbar, but adjusting the toolbar size will show just the folder name, and clicking it will display the contents as a menu.

[image]

Not that you asked, but this is a great way to store shortcuts. Save them to a particular folder and they become accessible easily without a browser shortcut bar.